# data section in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a question to clarify my confusion about the memory organization in computer in C++.

In C++, different data is put in different location. My understanding is like this.

1) data segment section,   where global and static data are located;

2) heap section,           the objects created by new

3) stack section,          the local variable

4) text section,           the code itself.

Is that right? Is there anything I missed or did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually that depends on the object format. Just to make it more confusing, in Mach-O, for example, all **constant** data will be stored in the `__TEXT` segment. And then there's also `__LINKEDIT` segment to help `dyld` for dynamically linking, etc.

Comment: [Here is a guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20150218203759/http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/cs106b/handouts/25-heap-stack-diagrams.pdf) that may help.

Comment: The main problem with your question are that you assume there's some sort of standard here, whereas there's just common practices.  While the organization you mention is common and reasonable, it isn't universal, and can vary across implementations.

Comment: Another problem is that the language standard (specification) does not require data sections or segments.  The language specifies the attributes (read or write, public, private) and the life time of an object.  The data sections depend on the compiler or translator and may be different between manufacturers and versions.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an article called "[C++ Internals :: Memory Layout](https://web.archive.org/web/20190917094831/http://www.codingfail.com/cpp-internals-memory-layout/)" which will clarify this for you.

Short excerpt from the article:

`.text segment`

> It's a **Read-Only**, fixed-size segment.
>
> The text segment, a.k.a. code segment, contains executable instructions provided by the compiler and assembler.

`.data segment`

> It's a **Read-Write**, fixed-size segment.
>
> The data segment, a.k.a. initialized data segment, contains initialized:
>
> - global variables (including global static variables)
> - static local variables.
>
> The segment's size depends on the size of the values in the source code, the values can be altered at run-time.

`.rdata/.rodata segment`

> It's a **Read-Only** segment
>
> The segments contains static unnamed data (like string constants)

`.bss segment`

> It's a **Read-Write** and adjacent to the .data segment.
>
> BSS segment, a.k.a. uninitialized data segment, contains statically-allocated (global and static) variables represented solely by zero-valued bits on program start. BSS stands for Block Started by Symbol, a pseudo-operation that existed in a very old assembler developed for the IBM.

`heap` & `stack`

You are quite right about those. Anyway, if you want to check some examples and get a closer look, please, refer to mentioned article.

Answer (score 1):

There are typically at least two data sections.  One with initialized globals, another without (BSS).  A stack section isn't typically emitted in the binary.

Of course, these kind of very implementation specific questions are kinda useless if you don't specify the implementation.

Comment: Yeah very implementation specific but over 15 years I've never worked with a linker that doesn't produce at least .text, .data and .bss. I've also encountered .sdata ( for all static variables ) quite a few times too