# Why the C++ global variable not affect to memory usage of program

Tags: c++, c

In my program I declare an initialized global variable (as an array).
But it only affects the size of executable file, the memory usage by the program was not affected.

My program is like that

```
char arr[1014*1024*100] = {1};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    while (true)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Size of executable file is 118MB but memory usage when running program was only 0.3MB

Can anyone explain for me?

Comment: Have you compiled with optimizations?

Comment: What do you use to get "memory usage"? (in general reading on "C data section" would provide an answer to actual question, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297706/data-section-in-c)

Answer (score 12):

Most operating systems used demand-paged virtual memory.

This means that when you load a program, the executable file for that program isn't allow loaded into memory immediately. Instead, virtual memory pages are set up to map the file to memory. When (and if) you actually refer to an address, that causes a page fault, which the OS then handles by reading the appropriate part of the file into physical memory, then letting the instruction re-execute.

In your case, you don't refer to `arr`, so the OS never pulls that data into memory.

If you were to look at the virtual address space used by your program (rather than the physical memory you're apparently now looking at), you'd probably see address space allocated for all of `arr`. The virtual address space isn't often very interesting or useful to examine though, so most things that tell you about memory usage will tell you only about the physical RAM being used to store actual data, not the virtual address space that's allocated but never used.

Even if you do refer to the data, the OS can be fairly clever: depending on how often you refer to the data (and whether you modify it), only part of the data may ever be loaded into RAM at any given time. If it's been modified, the modified portions can be written to the paging file to make room in RAM for data that's being used more often. If it's not modified, it can be discarded (because the original data can be re-loaded from the original file on disk whenever it's needed).

Comment: @VadaPoché: The first answer posted often gets a fair (unfair?) number of up-votes, as long as it's at least reasonably good. Such is life on SO.

Comment: @VadaPoché Fastest gun in the west has an edge, but takes a risk. Make a mistake and the early upvoters are freaking merciless. That said, +10 rep for an up and only -1 for a down means the trade off is usually in your favour.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Also can you answer in which scenario the in memory usage of program will really be increased if it is going to at all? e.g filling all values or referring to array

Comment: @JerryCoffin: If i change the global variable to const, the size of of executable file is only 35KB. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 4):

The reason your memory in use while your executable is executing is significantly smaller than the space required on your hard-drive (or solid-state drive) to store the executable is because you're not pulling the array itself into memory.

In your program, you never access or call your array—let alone bring into memory all at once in parallel. Because of that, the memory needed to run your executable is incredibly small when compared to the size of the executable (which has to store your massively large array).

I hope that makes sense. The difference between the two is that one is executing and one is stored on your computer's internal disk. Something is only brought into execution when it's brought into memory.

Comment: I already tried to access my array in main funtion but memory usage still not change. Do the array data is stored in disk drive throught out life time of program ?

Comment: @tuanpm the answer to this question is contained within Jerry Coffin's answer below. Demand-paged virtual memory is the keyword. Just because you declare a variable, memory isn't committed immediately.